# Error when trying to update data in Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I have a form on a table, when I make changes and try to save, I get this error:

```
1 error has occurred
#LABEL2536612111501127# must have some value.
```

Any idea what the heck LABEL is? and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a validation failed. Do you have validations that check for a not null field? 
Also, a field flagged as required will do the not null check by itself aswell.

I don't know why the substitution string is showing. A guess would be to check the page source of your page, and take a look at the html. I think you can map the numerical value you see to the different items on your form. Example taken from a simple form based on emp:

```
<td  colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left"><input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" value="27955991204660326497" /><input type="text" name="p_t02" id="P6_EMPNO" value="7788" size="32" maxlength="255" ...
<td  colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left"><input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" value="27955991414734326498" /><input type="text" id="P6_ENAME" name="p_t03" value="SCOTT" size="32" maxlength="10" ...
<td  colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left"><input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" value="27955991601403326498" /><input type="text" id="P6_JOB" name="p_t04" value="ANALYST" size="32" maxlength="9" ...
<td  colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left"><input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" value="27955991806798326498" /><input type="text" name="p_t05" id="P6_MGR" value="7566" size="32" maxlength="255" ...
<td  colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left"><input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" value="27955992024905326498" /><input type="text" class="datepicker" id="P6_HIREDATE" name="p_t06" maxlength="255" ...
<td  colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left"><input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" value="27955992219162326498" /><input type="text" name="p_t07" id="P6_SAL" value="3000" size="32" maxlength="255" ...
<td  colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left"><input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" value="27955993202832326504" /><input type="text" name="p_t08" id="P6_COMM" value=".22" size="32" maxlength="255" ...
<td  colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left"><input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" value="27955993400514326504" /><input type="hidden" name="p_t09" id="P6_DEPTNO_HIDDENVALUE" value="20" />
```

Look for the p_arg_names name, and then look at the value. Maybe a quick ctrl+f may find you the row on which this happens, and thus the item causing you headache?

Answer (score 0):

You can not select the primary key coloumn ...

most of these tools don't allow primary key column as updatable by the users if you remove the primary key column and press next you should be ok...